# Angular ng-class ternary doesn't update my template as the model changes

Tags: angularjs, ternary-operator, ng-class

When my page initially loads it properly sets the class using this `ng-class` ternary operator:

```
<div ng-class="{{day.current}} ? 'currPeriod' : 'notCurrPeriod'">
    {{day.date | date:"d"}}
</div>
```

*Note - this html is in a template, used by a directive, generated in an ng-repeat*

The value of the day `{{day.date | date:"d"}}` updates, but the class is not applied.

Oddly, my dev tools shows a disparity:

[image]

1 = true so it should evaluate to `currPeriod` but the element class is still `notCurrPeriod`. I tried `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the modal change, but that didn't work. **How can I get the template to rerun and apply this ternary?** or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div ng-class="{'currPeriod': day.current, 'notCurrPeriod': !day.current}">
  {{day.date | date:"d"}}
</div>
```

ng-class doesn't work this way, use the object syntax to acheive what you want, or you can either set a default style when the day isn't in the current period, and apply the class when it is, it would shorten your ng-class statement